# Instantiate interface when null

Tags: c#, constructor, interface, null

I working with interfaces for the first time to create loosely coupled code. In one of my classes I have the following constructor:

```
public ExceptionHandler(string logLocation = null, ICanLocalize localizer = null)
```

The localizer in this constructor is optional and is null by default (since not everyone wants to localize this class). Right now I only have the class `Localizer` that implements this interface. This class has a constructor with parameters for full functionality and a constructor without parameters for basic null checking. What I mean with this is that both constructors set a bool that indicates if the class is properly initialized. In case it's not (empty constructor) default values will be returned without localizing them.

So in my code I can have

```
_localizer.GetString("key", "optional fallback value");
```

In case it's properly initialized this will return 'key' in English or 'sleutel' in Dutch. If not properly initialized, 'optional fallback value' will be returned (or `key` if no fallback value was set). In order to achieve this behavior I do the following in the constructor of the `ExceptionHandler`:

```
_localizer = localizer ?? new Localizer();
```

This obviously tightly couples the classes together again which is not what was intended. I discovered that I'd done this after refactoring my `Localizer` class to have the intended behavior.

Now, one of the solutions I though of was to add a `localizer.CreateLocalizer()` to the interface that uses the empty constructor in the `Localizer` class. Unfortunately this has no use since an exception will be thrown because `localizer` is null. An other approach I tried was to add a static method to the interface but this also failed because interfaces can't have statics.

Right now I'm clueless how I can tackle this problem. Is my only option to check in the `ExceptionHandler` if the `localizer` is null and anticipate it inside this class or is there another solution I didn't think of yet? What about factories, do these have a use here and how does this effect the coupling of my code?

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, you shouldn't re-invent the square wheel but use an existing wheel. What you're trying to do is called [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). And probably you should learn about [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) too.

What about just using a framework like [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md)?

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<IExceptionHandler>().ImplementedBy<ExceptionHandler>());
container.Register(Component.For<ILocalizer>().ImplementedBy<Localizer>());

IExceptionHandler handler = container.Resolve<IExceptionHandler>();

// If there's a constructor with a registered component it will inject
// it automatically, so if you set the injected ILocalizer to a public property
// of the IExceptionHandler implementation constructor, you'll get the defined
// implementation for your localizer!
handler = container.Localizer;
```

There're many options out there. For example [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/).